# Correct way to make \externalfigure[] to look in only current directory of ConTeXt file?

Tags: floats, context

I'm trying a document directory structure like the following:

```
proj/proj.tex
proj/env.tex
proj/product/product.tex
proj/product/entries/comp1/entry.tex
proj/product/entries/comp1/image.pdf
proj/product/entries/comp2/entry.tex
proj/product/entries/comp2/image.pdf
```

I'm compiling `project.tex` from within the `proj/product` directory.

In `comp1/entry.tex`, I'd like to refer to the `comp1/image.pdf` file using an `\externalfigure` macro without having to specify the path to the component:

```
\placefigure[][]{caption}{\externalfigure[image]}
```

I used the following to set up a path to search for figures:

```
\setupexternalfigures[directory={entries/comp1}]
```

But notice that I also have a `comp2` folder which also has an `entry.tex` and `image.pdf`. I tried putting the following line in `comp2/entry.tex`:

```
\setupexternalfigures[directory={entries/comp2}]
```

and expected it to find the `image.pdf` file in the `comp2` folder, but it reused the `image.pdf` file in the `comp1` folder instead. Using `\enabletrackers[graphics.locating]` confirmed that these directories are cumulative.

So, how do I reset this directory list? Or is there a better way to do this while avoiding my having to rename all of the files to something unique?

I tried `\setupexternalfigures[location=local]` since the documentation says that makes ConTeXt look in the "current" directory, but "current" seems to mean the directory of the product file, not the component file.

---

One idea I had was to defined a `here` variable of some sort containing the current subdirectory that I can redefine in every component. Then I would be able to use `\placefigure[][]{caption}{\externalfigure[\here/image]}`. Would this be a good solution and how would I do this?

Comment: I think you are thinking backwards, or maybe I'm thinking backwards, but it can't be a `local` location, but `global`. If you have a file in `comp1` there is no need to do anything. Forget about `local`. Now, if the file is in `entries` the `location=global` along with the dir path, must be setup

Comment: I've tried that and what I get is the same image (with the same filename) twice, instead of two different images.